# Connection between fractional derivatives and the Eulers constant

Tags: inverse, fractional-calculus, euler-mascheroni-constant

I was recently exploring the set of equations such that $\frac{d^n}{dx^n}f(x)=f^{-1}(x)$.

Through some not too difficult algebra, I found the solution $f(x)=ax^b$ where $a=\frac{(b-n)!}{b!}^{\frac{1}{b-n+1}}$ and $b=\frac{1}{2}(n+\sqrt{n^2+4})$.

I then noticed that the intersection between $y=x$ and $y=\lim_{n \rightarrow 0}\left(\frac{d^n}{dx^n}f(x)\right)$ happens at the point $(e^{1-\gamma},e^{1-\gamma})$.
I have verified this identity to at least 6 digits using desmos, but I have no idea how to prove this identity. Any help? Attached is the desmos sheet with a bunch of the work. https://www.desmos.com/calculator/r2qfcqlpi9

Comment: You meant $\frac{d^n}{dx^n}f(x)=\frac{1}{f(x)}$ ? What is your definition of $\frac{d^n}{dx^n}$ ? (note $\Gamma'(1) = -\gamma$)

Comment: no. I mean the inverse of f(x). My definition of $d^n\over dx^n$ is the nth derivative with respect to x

Comment: Restrict to $f(x) = a x^b$ and use [this definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_calculus#Fractional_derivative_of_a_basic_power_function) of the fractional derivative of $a x^b$. As $\Gamma(s+1) = s \Gamma(s)$ the limit $n \to 0$ involves $\Gamma'(1) = -\gamma$.

Comment: That makes sense. If you make it into an answer, I'd be happy to accept it.

Comment: It is your question. Can *you* put it into an answer ?

Comment: Sure, I just thought you would want rep for what you'd already given me, which I would consider complete enough to be an answer. (with it, I can get the details nailed down)